# Problem with annotation spring context with differ modules

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

Greeteng.

I made application based on spring annotation configuration. This application is moduled, i'm build it with maven.
I scan application to find Configurations in one module.

```
public class ClientUserDAOImplTest {
```

```
private static UserDAOLocal userDAOLocal;

@BeforeClass
public static void start() {
    beginDate = new Date();
    ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("package");
    userDAOLocal = ac.getBean(UserDAOLocal.class);
}
```

...

I made class annotated with @Configuration in another module. 
When i try to construct ApplicationContext, it fails with so stacktrace:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: package.ClientUserDAOImplTest
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.09 sec (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:75)
        at package.UserDAOImplTest.start(ClientUserDAOImplTest.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:237)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:118)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:89)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:238)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:384)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "package.ClientInitConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cee25681"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:488)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:626)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        ... 37 more
```

**litte FIX.**

Problem is at test stage. So, jar for other module is already ready and jar for tests of first module is not created and run as just .class files.

Answer (score 0):

If the configuration is annotated and in a different base package than `"package"`, the context will not pick it up.  You need to tell the app context to [scan](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#scan%28java.lang.String...%29) the other packages as well.

**EDIT** Sorry missed the guts of the exception.  Did you sign the jars differently?  They need to be signed with the same cert.

Comment: All config files are at "package" and subpackages.

Comment: jars of my project are made by maven. I didn't specify anything about the signing it. Spring is from maven repository too.

Comment: It definitely is a problem with the jars being signed.  Maven might be pulling them in.  Check http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-18118.html  - to verify you could try using jarsigner to see what's signed and not

Comment: My jar files are haven't signature. In really, the first module is testing, so, there no jar file there.